# How to force commit entity in @Transactional mode

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring data jpa and jdbc (using entityManager.unwrap(Session.class) ) connection.
My request flows through 3 method. 1st -> 2nd ->3rd.
1st and 3rd are annotated with @Transactional.
In 1st and 2nd method saving entity through JPA CRUD repository.
In 3rd method using basic jdbc query to retrieve values saved in 2nd method.
As we know in @Transaction entities are not committed to database until JPA commit the transaction.
I used saveAndFlush also in 2nd method but can not see retrieve updated values in method 3 using jdbc query.

**1st Method - update()**

```
@Transactional
@Override
public ApiResponse update(RequestInput input) {
    ApiResponse response = doRestOfWork(input);   // calling 2nd method
    // .... some other entity save....
}
```

**2nd Method - doRestOfWork()** : setting status=true and calling saveAndFlush method

```
@Override
public ApiResponse doRestOfWork(Request request) {
    Insight insight = insightRepository.findOne(request.getTypeId());
    insight.setStatus(true);
    insightRepository.saveAndFlush(insight);

    processOperation();    // calling 3rd method
}
```

**3rd method - processOperation()** : retrieving updated status value through jdbc connection.

```
@Transactional
public void processOperation() {
Connection conn = null;
        SessionImplementor sessionImpl = (SessionImplementor) entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        try {
            conn = sessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();
            Connection conn = null;
            String stmt = "SELECT status from insight";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
               boolean value = rs.getBoolean(status);   // returning false, i want this to return true as already set true in 2nd method and called saveAndFlush 
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    } finally {
        JdbcUtility.closeResources(conn, ps, rs);
    }
}
```

**InsightRepository** is extending JpaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface InsightRepository extends JpaRepository<Insight, Long> {}
```

> I want updated value of status (which is boolean true - updated in method 2) in method 3.
>   How to achieve this ?

**Update**

I searched a lot and do not think that if a method is annotated with  [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) then you can commit changes before completing JPA transaction. So the solution is to remove [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation and use entityManager.getTransaction() if want to control over JPA transaction.

Comment: Why not annotate the second method as @Transactional, instead of the third one? Doing only a `select` does not need an explicit transaction. Also: I doubt that `saveAndFlush` commits the change.

Comment: Because method 3 has other  fetch and update JPA transaction. Just for simplicity i added only one select operation.  saveAndFlush is not committing the transaction. This is what my question how to commit changes in second method.

Comment: You can annotate both. The third method will overtake the first transaction.

Comment: I searched a lot and do not think that if a method is annotated with Transactional then you can commit changes before completing JPA transaction. So the solution is to either remove Transactional annotation or use entityManager.getTransaction() to control over JPA transaction.

Comment: If method 3 is using the same transaction as method 2, it will see the update although the update is not yet committed. If you really want a commit before entering into method 3 than extract the update code of method 2 into an own sub method which is annotated Transactional.

Comment: Ofcourse you cannot see it because you are opening a new connection. As the data isn't commit you will not see it. Your code is overly complex. Just use `JdbcTemplate` to execute the query which will use the same connection as hibernate is currently using instead of using a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Create a method (4th method) for update with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotation in a bean different from the 2nd Method and change second method as calling 4th method like this :

```
@Component //or Service etc..
public class AnotherBean{

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void doUpdateWork(Request request){
    Insight insight = insightRepository.findOne(request.getTypeId());
    insight.setStatus(true);
    insightRepository.save(insight);
  }
}
```

and

```
    @Override
    public ApiResponse doRestOfWork(Request request) {
        anotherBean.doUpdateWork(request);
        processOperation();    // calling 3rd method
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is going to work because from the docs Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW just suspends (and not commits) the current transaction and just creates a new one. What I think you should add is to obtain the entity manager instance and commit it in the "parent" transactional method

Comment: As per the spec, this is suppose to work. But its not working.

Comment: @Aladin , method with **REQUIRES_NEW** commits its operatins with its own transaction, it doesn't wait parent transaction's commit. Key point is method with **REQUIRES_NEW** propagation must be in another bean,[because of spring proxies](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to controll transaction, dont use `@Transactional`

```
em; //entityManager

Transaction tx=em.getTransaction();
try{
   tx.begin();
   //do work
   tx.commit(); // comminted transaction 
 // start another transaction if you need to, doo more work etc.
...
}
```

This is most basic and fundamental block of code for using JPA for atomic operations.

Also there is no need to `unwrap` entity manager, use pure JPA. By unwrapping you are binding current implementation to JPA provider which is in contrary to JPA idea of independency from underlying JPA implementation provider. In other words, it will stop working if for some reasons Spring would change its JPA implementation from Hibrnate to eg. EclipseLink.

Comment: But i have to use both JPA and pure jdbc connection(for complex join queries). when i am fetching value through preparedStatement in method 3, i need updated status value which was savedAndFlushed in method 2 through JPA transaction (not yet committed). Are you saying if i remove @Transactional annotation then updated value will reflect in SELECT query ?

Comment: Im saying if you need to controll tranaction flow, dont use `@Transactional` and do it manually like showed above. I doubd that you need to use jdbc connection, as you can perform native querios with JPA.

Comment: Spring throws a exception, when we try this. (v.5.2.2)